# Dynamically joining list elements based on key

Tags: python, pandas, list

My data starts with a pandas dataframe. Then I convert the column which I am interested in into a python list and I am trying to join certain elements of that list into one based on some specific rules.

My example list may look like this:

```
list_1 = ['country: US', 'firstname: John', 'displayName: A', 'JohnS123', 'address: 123 main st', 'baltimore', 'MD', '12345', 'email:jsmith@email.com']
```

I am looking for all the indexes that contain a ' : ' in them. `list_1[0]` contains ' : ' in it so it's okay. `list_1[1]` also contains the character so it is also okay. `list_1[3]` does not contain ' : ' so I am trying to join it with `list_1[2]` by adding a ' , ' in between them. So in the new list `list_1[2]` would look like, `'displayName: A, JohnS123'`.

Additionally, I am trying to add all the indices that do not contain ' : ' to the `index-1` until the I reach the next item in the list that contains ' : '.

Here's what the new list would look like after executing.

```
new_list = ['country: US', 'firstname: John', 'displayName: A, JohnS123', 'address: 123 main st, baltimore, MD, 12345', 'email:jsmith@email.com']
len(list_1) -> 9
len(new_list) -> 5
```

I've trying to do this by setting up different algorithms using lists, but if it can also be done through pandas I am open to both options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do:

```
# setup
list_1 = ['country: US', 'firstname: John', 'displayName: A', 'JohnS123', 'address: 123 main st', 'baltimore', 'MD',
          '12345', 'email:jsmith@email.com']
s = pd.Series(list_1, dtype='string')

# group by contiguous chunks were the first element contains :
res = s.groupby(s.str.contains(':').astype(int).cumsum()).agg(', '.join)

print(res)
```

**Output**

```
1                                   country: US
2                               firstname: John
3                      displayName: A, JohnS123
4    address: 123 main st, baltimore, MD, 12345
5                        email:jsmith@email.com
dtype: string
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This does appear to work if the list is small, but when I try to run on my original list in jupyter notebook the kernel keeps dying. Maybe there is a way to do this in place? Thanks.

Comment: How large is your list? Also I don't think this can be done "in-place" strings are immutable in Python

Comment: The original column which I am turning into a list has over 1.4 million rows.